# Odoo v7 ir.ui.menu translation

Tags: menu, translation, odoo

For a specific custom need I'm translating occurrences of some words ("projects", for instance) with a different term than the original translation.

I'm using the

> "Export translation" > editing the CSV > "Import translation"

Everything runs fine, except for some top menu items, eg.

> "Projects". Within Translations > Terms > Translated terms

I find half a dozen of occurrences of the word "Project", all of them of the field "ir.ui.menu,name".

They don't appear in the exported CSV.

How could I translate them, without using the web interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually populate translate file (for example edit exported csv file):

```
#. module: module_name_you_translating
#: model:ir.ui.menu,name:module_name_you_translating.menu_name
msgid "Project"
msgstr "Your translation"
```

You can populate multiple lines like second one if there are different menu called "Project", so it would translate with same translation. If you need to translate same "Project" term with different translation (for example depending on menu name or whatever), you can populate such manual "blocks" for each translation.